# I have input buttons created dynamically by javascript which should call a server c# function but they dont

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this JavaScript in my page that creates dynamically some buttons in a table, and these buttons must call a function on the server side:

The JavaScript code is this:

```
var rowContent = document.createElement('td');
rowContent.style.width = '12%';
var chk = document.createElement('input');
chk.type = 'submit';
chk.value = 'Adicionar';
chk.setAttribute('Id', 'Sub' +id);
chk.name = "ftps"
chk.setAttribute('runat', 'server');
chk.setAttribute('onserverclick', 'BtnAdicionar_Click');

rowContent.appendChild(chk);
```

And the Server side function is like this:

```
public void BtnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); //just to see if something happens.
}
```

PS.: Im in a page that's in a MasterPage.

If i get the code of the button generated by the Inspect Element of Google Chrome, it will give me this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Adicionar" id="Sub1" name="ftps" runat="server" onserverclick="BtnAdicionar_Click">
```

And if i put this HTML code, directly on the page, it works. Just doesn't work when the button is generated dynamically.

Could any body help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some concepts here.

First of all, there's no way to create a server element with javascript, simply because it's a client side language. Have in mind that when you declare a `<asp:Button runat="server">` tag it will be interpreted by the ASP.NET engine and will be rendered as HTML (`<input type="submit" />` in this case). Also,`onserverclick` event does not exist.

If you really need to create this element with Javascript, you can use jQuery on click event to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods as [described here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) .

A better solution is to create the Button dynamically in the code behind of the page, something like:

```
 TableCell td = new TableCell();
 Button button = new Button();
 button.Text = "Adicionar";
 button.ID = "Sub" + id; // Whatever "id" is
 button.Click += new EventHandler(BtnAdicionar_Click);
 td.Controls.Add(td);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the attribute to:

```
chk.setAttribute('onclick', 'BtnAdicionar_Click');
```

Comment: This is wrong, `onclick` will try to call a Javascript function `BtnAdicionar_Click`. The code shows that `BtnAdicionar_Click` is a server side method. Note that his code is mixing server and client side behaviors.